# Change class to all images in div - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I included jQuery plugin to my project named [SuperSlides](http://nicinabox.com/superslides/), but it automatically resize every image in a slide to "background". This can by prevented by add class '.preserve' to image. I want to add this class to every image in a div (#container). Can anyone help me with this script?

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#container img").addClass("preserve")
```

Comment: If you want all images only one level inside of your container you can use $("#container > img").addClass("preserve")

Answer (score 1):

**[LIVE EXAMPLE HERE >>](http://jsfiddle.net/9naM8/)**

```
 $(function(){
   $('#container img').addClass("preserve");
 });
```